# How can I open the HTML file in the assets folder?

Tags: java, android

```
Intent mhelp = new Intent();
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/help.html");
mhelp.setData(uri);
mhelp.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
mhelp.setClassName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
startActivity(mhelp);
```

That's my code and I put the HTML file in the `/assets/help.html`. but when I run the program to see the "The requested file was not found. help.html" of the message.

I don't want to use the WEBVIEW widget.

Comment: The file is in your application's assets folder, but you are asking the Browser app to open it up from its assets folder. Actually, you should be using WebView. See the [guideline](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Comment: why you don't want to use the webview?